# Is it possible to add a child to a UK credit card?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-score, children

Many parties suggest that parents should add their baby child to their credit card so that the child can build a credit score as soon as possible. Unfortunately, these all seem to be USA sources, and I cannot find any in Britain.

Is it possible to add a child to a credit card in England?

- If so, which one?
- If not, how can one build a credit score for a British child before they turn 18?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. The minimum age at which a person can have a credit card in the UK is 18.

Any attempt to search for the minimum age for credit cards in the UK confirms this (e.g. [Money Supermarket](https://www.moneysupermarket.com/credit-cards/can-i-get-a-credit-card/)). However, finding the legislation which backs this up is less clear cut. I believe the most likely candidate is the [Minors’ Contracts Act 1987](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1987/13), with the definition of "minor" being 18 across the UK, but defined in [three](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1969/46/section/1) [different](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/apni/1969/28/contents) [Acts](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1969/39/).

Accordingly, [you can't build](https://www.finder.com/uk/credit-card-guide-under-21-users) a [credit history](https://www.experian.co.uk/consumer/experian-credit-report.html) before you're 18.